# Splitting arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am new to Perl
I have below data into arrays, each product is a value of this array,

```
 print @array

 Product A
      Date=2.3.13
      Value=100
      Time=2.12

 Product B
      Date=4.5.12
      value=20
      Description=Goods

 Product C
      ...
      ...
```

These products can change from A to Z, and their attributes can change as well, can some one help me getting data in below format

```
 Product         Date      Value        Descrip      Time
 A               2.3.13    100          -Nil-        -Nil-
 B               4.5.12    20           Goods
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that. If you write something and come across an insurmountable problem then come here and explain and we will help you out. We're not about writing entire solutions.

Comment: I assume this data has come from a file? It's probably best to use a `while` loop to process your data a line at a time than to throw it all into an array.

Comment: Is this homework? The product names don't look like real data.

Comment: I also wouldn't be stuffing it into an array. This looks more like data suited for putting into a hash.

Answer (score -1):

Based on additional input from the author and the comments, here's an updated answer.

1. Prepare a data structure (hash) to store data for one product.
2. Read in the file product-by-product, by parsing consequtive lines. Store the data for one product in memory.
3. Print the data as soon as you are finished with one product (an empty line seems to be a separator). Clear the data. Repeat.

In total, this would look like this:

```
my $empty = {
    name => "",
    date => "",
    value => ""
    # etc
};

my $product = $empty;

while (my $line = <$file>) {
    if ($line =~ m/^Product\s+(.*)$) {
        $product->{name} = $1;
    } elsif ($line =~ m/^\s+Date=(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$/) {
        $product->{date} = $1;
    } elsif () {
        # etc.
    } elsif ($line eq "") {
        # Empty line
        print $product->{name} . "\t" . $product->{date} . "\n"; #etc
        # Clear the product data
        $product = $empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: While it's questionable what the OP actually has in the array, it's pretty clear that it isn't an array of hashes. My guess is that they've just done `my @array = <>` which doesn't really advance the solution at all as all that's happened is that the data is now in memory instead of on disk.

Comment: Perhaps we should wait till we know the data. I'll edit my answer and add an assumtion of the data being hashes.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. As I have mentioned this is the first time I am trying this... and as you have predicted this is from a file, and file has the same what I have given.. what I managed to do is split these lines using "split(/\n\n/,$line)" (because each product has two ) and put them in a array, so if I want to call each product, I can print them by array[0], array[1], and then I decided to put each array values in to hash, then get the output as desired.

may be this approach is entirely wrong.. expecting some help please.. Thanks again.

Comment: @AJF: Please edit your question and include your code. That way we can see what you're doing and where you'er going wrong. Otherwise, it's really hard to help.